# Bootstrap 4 Tooltip with Ajax Call Return

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm confined to Bootstrap 4 and jQuery with this project, so please only suggest recommendations that fall within this scope.

Initially, the tooltip wasn't doing anything. Then I found this [resource](https://codepen.io/team/bootstrap/pen/qBNGbYK) that explained using a `selector` is required.

I tried two different approaches, with varied results.

First, here's the basic HTML:

```
<span class="show-details" data-url="https://example.com/controller">Example</span>
```

**Approach 1:**

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '.show-details',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,   
    title: function() {
        let url = $(this).data('url');
        $.ajax(url, {
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response); // <-- Shows correct value
                return response; // <-- Empty string -- why?
            }
        });
    }
});
```

With this approach `console.log(response)` **returns the value I do want**. However, `return response` appears to be empty, as nothing is actually returned to the tooltip.

**Approach 2:**

```
var toolTip = '';

$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '.show-details',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    title: function() {
        let url = $(this).data('url');
        $.ajax(url, {
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response); // <-- Shows correct value
                toolTip = response;
            }
        });
        return toolTip; // <-- 2nd hover attempt returns correct
    }
});
```

With this version, the returned value is closer, as the value is displayed on the 2nd hover attempt -- the first hover attempt is still empty, BUT hovering a second time shows correctly.

I think the issue has something to do with Popover being called twice, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12563).

In short, how do I get the correct returned value on the initial hover attempt?

*Suggesting to use `async: false` is a poor solution.*

Comment: The function executed in title, will not wait for the completion of the ajax request to return, a way to solve it is add `async: false` before success, in `Approach 2:`.

Comment: @Benilson Thanks for your note. I've updated my question to reference async and commented where values are correct to help further troubleshooting.